# Rainfall, climate change data

Tags: africa, climate

I'm looking for annual (or monthly) rainfall data over time and by country (specifically, for sub-Saharan African countries). I've been able to find data up to the year 2000. I know there has got to be more recent data but I'm having trouble finding it! Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The European Centre for Medium Range Weather Forecasts hosts a database with this information here: http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc/

They require you to create an account (free) before you can request data. The data is available per lat/lon grid point, so you'll have to look up which grid points are within which country.

As for the data, you'll probably want the `Total precipitation` field (this also includes hail and snow, but that won't be much in the sub-Sahara).